# .net to QT networking outside home network

Tags: c#, qt, networking, azure

Hi I want develop a communicate from a.net application running on Amazon AWC or microsoft azure
to a QT application in a Linux device in a local network (connected to Internet using a router).

I tried with QTWebApp in Qt and create a server in the device. it work in a local network. but cant find the app without port directing in the router.

**basically i want someting like p2p kind of connection.
when QT app switch on, it to send a message to .net application with ip,port etc witch can be use by .net app anytime to connect to the QT app.**

Somthing like signalR or p2p or any good solution....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it without any changes to the port redirection in the router, you'd be best off opening a connection from the Qt app and polling the .net application on the server for data and then acting upon it in the Qt application. Trying to do it so you're opening a connection to the Qt application from the .net application will require a fixed IP and a redirected port.